# Чем отличаются LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 и LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.UTF-8?

Tags: linux, locale

Будет ли разница (и какая) между установкой значения переменной локали LC_CTYPE в

```
en_US.UTF-8
```

и

```
ru_RU.UTF-8
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

так спросите у программы *locale* и сравните результаты:

```
$ LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" locale -k LC_CTYPE
$ LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8" locale -k LC_CTYPE
```

---

у меня в системе вывод идентичен:

```
$ LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" locale -k LC_CTYPE | md5sum
7d8380e3b913432296b6d7027f97c153  -
$ LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8" locale -k LC_CTYPE | md5sum
7d8380e3b913432296b6d7027f97c153  -
```